# Using Protocol Buffers with Golang and "option go_package"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

From here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package

It is written:

> There is no correlation between the Go import path and the package
> specifier in the .proto file. The latter is only relevant to the
> protobuf namespace, while the former is only relevant to the Go
> namespace. Also, there is no correlation between the Go import path
> and the .proto import path.

So, if I understand correctly - the "package" in your .proto file is just for importing other .proto's whereas the "option go_package" is what determines the package name generated into your .go files.

My question is why was this done?  If you have the following in your .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package cool.app.v1;
option go_package = "github.com/some-user/cool-app/pkg/app/proto";
message Test{}
```

Then in other proto files you can reference Test using cool.app.v1.Test.  But, then in the generated golang file - you end up with the following package (that last string after the last "/"):

```
package proto
```

Why wouldn't protoc just use the package specified in the .proto file?  Are there other languages generated by protoc that require the same "option" override for the package name?

Comment: Protobuf predates Go by eight years. The compiler itself is written in C++, only the Go plugin (protoc-gen-go) is written in Go. There is no technical reason to make the package names identical, so not enforcing that provides flexibility at no cost.

Comment: I'll remove the bit about protocol buffers being written in golang - not sure where I heard that.  

I understand your point about flexibility - but if you don't specify a "option go_package" in your .proto file - why not default to the package that you've already specified in your .proto file?